# Creator Owner not receiving rights

Tags: windows-server-2008, folder-redirection

I'm having trouble setting up folder redirection on Windows Server 2008R2.  For some unknown reason, the CREATOR OWNER built-in account doesn't seem to be adding the user to the ACL for their folder.

The share's permissions are:

```
Authenticated Users - Full Control
```

I've gone over the permissions at the topmost level ten times over.  I have the topmost level set to:

```
Include inheritable permissions from this object's parent - UNCHECKED

Administrators - Full Control -> this folder, subfolders and files
SYSTEM - Full Control -> this folder, subfolders and files
Domain Admins - Full Control  -> this folder, subfolders and files
EVERYONE - Create Folders / Append Data, List folder / read data -> This folder only
CREATOR OWNER - Full Control -> Subfolders and files only
```

For each of these:

```
Apply these permissions to objects and/or containers within this container only - UNCHECKED
```

Whenever the user logs on, the system creates all of the folders.  After login, the user receives:

```
Windows cannot access \\servername\share$\username\Desktop
```

As the user, if I try to navigate to the folder they receive "access is denied"

Here's the strange thing, if I goto the topmost level and replace all child object permissions, it adds the account to the ACL.  I'm open to any ideas at this point.

Comment: If you use a test account and manually create a folder for the user account \\servername\share$\testAccountUsername, then create the subfolder Desktop, that folder has the correct permissions?

Comment: I manually created a folder inside, it does have the correct permissions.